# Openweathermap API for multiple geographic coordinates float error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file that has geographic coordinates pairs for multiple cities

```
import requests
import smtplib
import urllib


def get_location():
    geocode={}
    latlon=open('latlononly.txt', 'r')
    for line in latlon:
        (lat, lon)=line.split(',')
        geocode[lat]=lon.strip()
    return geocode
def get_weather(geocode):
    api='xxxx'
    for x, y in geocode.items():
        url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=imperial&appid='+api+''.format(x,y)
        weather_r=requests.get(url)
        weather_j=weather_r.json()
        print(weather_j)

geocode=get_location()
get_location()
get_weather(geocode)
print(geocode)
```

The error right is that '{'cod': '400', 'message': '{0} is not a float'}'

How do I translate the .format() to be a float?  Or do I have change the geocode dictionary to a float before that?  I want to read in the txt file so I can change it on the fly instead of using the Openweathermap API for multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the brackets around the number that is you value. So it would be:

```
url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=0&lon=1&units=imperial&appid="
```

This worked just fine for me, so hopefully for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following: you try to format empty string.
Solution is the following:

```
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=imperial&appid={2}'.format(x, y, api)
```